# How to bind line to a circle that is inside another node in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, binding

I have created a custom node (this is just a VBox derived node) that contains two sockets (circles) at right and left sides.

[image: Custom nodes with IO sockets]

The purpose is to connect them by dragging the sockets to another ones, and there should be drawn a line between them.

[image: Custom nodes connected after dragging the line]

Here I am just getting mouse x and y positions and drawing line between the sockets when drag detected on one of them. It is straightforward, but there is a problem when I move nodes.

[image: Custom nodes moved after connecting them with lines]

That is the lines are not bound to the sockets (circles). When I tried to bind them to the sockets (circles) centerX and centerY position, they were bound incorrectly because centerX and centerY positions are returned according VBox not a AnchorPane. I added my custom nodes to AnchorPane and the lines are drawn on it as well. So this is the problem circles are inside VBox and lines are inside AnchorPane.

How to bind circles and lines when they have different parents?
(I strictly want them to be bound)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I was able to do is to calculate scene X and Y coordinates of the item using `localToSceneTransform` property and use these values as starting/ending point for the line.

Here's some sample code:

```java
...
Line line = new Line();
line.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
line.setStrokeWidth(5.0);

Circle start = new Circle();
Pane startWrapper = new Pane();
startWrapper.getChildren().add(start);

Circle end = new Circle();
Pane endWrapper = new Pane();
endWrapper.getChildren().add(end);

start.localToSceneTransformProperty().addListener((_observable, _old, _new) -> {
   Point2D posInScene = _new.transform(0, 0);

    line.setStartX(posInScene.getX());
    line.setStartY(posInScene.getY());
});

end.localToSceneTransformProperty().addListener((_observable, _old, _new) -> {
   Point2D posInScene = _new.transform(0, 0);

    line.setEndX(posInScene.getX());
    line.setEndY(posInScene.getY());
});
...
```

How it works: whenever you drag parent (not circle), the property `localToSceneTransform` gets updated which will give you fresh info about circle's transform (note: circle still has the same coordinate relative to parent, but will have different for scene)

It will cover infinite nesting problem as well

Here's the screenshot of the app using this code snippet

[image: screenshot]

You may ask "Why do I need to use 0 in `_new.transform(0, 0);`". The problem is that you still need to use circle local point (relative point within same parent, that's why it is called `localToSceneTransform`). In this case `0` is the center of the circle relative to its parent. For controls it will be top leftmost coordinate, but not sure.